# Bypassing Cloudflare's upload max

Tags: cloudflare

I'm using Cloudflare to speed up my site and it works great for that.  Unfortunately, some of my users will need to upload videos to my site which are larger than the allowed max on Cloudflare (i.e. 300MB in size).  Is there any way to tell Cloudflare to ignore post requests from my upload form?

Comment: Checking that "cloudflare" tag ... it seems that few questions get answers here. Did you consider that when using a commercial product, you maybe use the support forums of that commercial product directly?

Comment: After a week of waiting for a response from them, I thought I might ask here...

Comment: I hope you are not paying to much of money for their "support" then; and as said: don't expect to many helpful answers here either.

Comment: Luckily I'm using the free version at the moment.  :)

Comment: Probably their answer is: "use the non-free version" ;-)

Comment: Heh!  They still have a limit on the non-free version which won't work for my needs.

Comment: I guess, like with any commercial product: throwing enough money over the fence could force them to do whatever you want to happen. Its all about *amounts* ;-)

Answer (score 4):

It looks like all I needed to do was "chunk" the request into smaller pieces.

Comment: That's what I did as well

Comment: Could you maybe explain what that is? Because I am also facing the same problem right now :L

Comment: The idea is that that you break your file into smaller pieces ("chunking" is the lingo).  Here's one article about it: https://api.video/blog/tutorials/uploading-large-files-with-javascript.  However, my guess (hope!) is that you're using a library to help with the upload and many of them have chunking as an option.

Answer (score 2):

You can also change your dns settings to disable the cloud protection. (proxy status = dns only)

Answer (score 1):

You will have to upgrade your package. [Read this article from Cloudflare](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/201303340-How-can-I-change-the-client-maximum-upload-size-)

Comment: I would still like the upload to be limited by my own server, if possible.

Comment: There are many ways to limit the upload from your server. Most of the time you can alter this in the php.ini (if you work with PHP). Just google a bit around for that. It depends on what kind of server you have (shared hosting, VPS etc..) and what language you use (PHP, Python, Ruby etc).